# Lambda - headObject fails (NotFound) though objectCreated is the event

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

In a lambda function with the event: `s3:ObjectCreated:*`, calling head object on the created object returns a NotFound error.

```
module.exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
    try {
        const Bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        const Key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
        console.log('Bucket', Bucket);
        console.log('Key', Key);

        const objectHead = await s3.headObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();
        console.log('Alas! I will never discover that the objectHead is:', objectHead);

        callback();
    } catch(err) {
        console.error('Error', err);
        callback(err);
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
{ 
    NotFound: null
    message: null,
    code: 'NotFound',
    region: null,
    time: 2018-02-19T11:06:35.894Z,
    requestId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    extendedRequestId: 'XXX.....XXX',
    cfId: undefined,
    statusCode: 404,
    retryable: false,
    retryDelay: 77.24564264820208 
}
```

I've noticed that it says `region null` in the error. I suspect this is irrelevant as I'm 99% sure I'm setting it correctly:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: 'us-east-1'
});
```

Here's the serverless.yml function declaration in case anybody's curious:

```
obj_head:
  handler: obj_head.handler
  events:
    - s3:
        bucket: ${self:provider.environment.BUCKET_NAME}
        event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
  role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/RoleWithAllS3PermissionsEver
```

And here is a sample for a received event:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.0",
            "eventSource": "aws:s3",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
            "eventTime": "2018-02-19T11:03:46.761Z",
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "AWS:XXX"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "X.X.X.X"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": "X",
                "x-amz-id-2": "X/X/X"
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "14122133-28e8-4cd9-907c-af328334c56b",
                "bucket": {
                "name": "BUCKET_NAME",
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": "X"
                },
                "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "input.key",
                    "size": X,
                    "eTag": "X",
                    "sequencer": "X"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It's puzzling that the object head isn't found though the very event that triggered the function is the object's creation.

Am I doing something wrong?
Any thoughts on where to look?

Comment: Can you post the actual event?
btw, I think `await` won't be available in lambda (current highest node version in lambda is 6.10)

Comment: I'll add the event to the original request.
For es2017 support I just transpile with babel.

Comment: As if this wasn't weird enough, it sometimes does work. I suspect the event might be triggered before the object's upload has finished. Unfortunately I don't see any event called s3:ObjectCreated:Complete that I can use instead. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-event-types-and-destinations

Comment: The event definitely does not fire before the upload is complete.  There are two probable causes: special characters in the object key (notably `+`), or you are trying to discover whether the object exists (e.g. trying to `HEAD` or `GET` the object) *before* you upload it.  That causes side effects.

Comment: The event definitely does not fire before the upload is complete.  There are two probable causes: special characters in the object key (notably `+`), or you are trying to discover whether the object exists (e.g. trying to `HEAD` or `GET` the object) *before* you upload it.  That causes side effects.

Comment: This occurs with object keys as simple as `file.txt`. And I don't understand what you mean by trying to discover whether the object exists before I upload. The only tie I call headObject is in that lambda function that happens _after_ the event is triggered. I actually am trying to get the object's metadata, and not just make sure that it's uploaded.

Comment: @NimrodGeva if you are trying to check whether an object exists before uploading it (for example, trying to avoid overwriting an existing object with the same key), this breaks the S3 immediate consistency guarantee on read-after-write of new objects and can cause this behavior.  It looks like your issue may be something else, in this case.

Comment: I was mistaken regarding the object key. As you originally suggested, the issue was with special characters. The key was simple enough but the bucket had a special character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object keyname value is URL encoded, and this was causing the issue. This behaviour is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html):

> The s3 key provides information about the bucket and object involved
>   in the event. Note that the object keyname value is URL encoded. For
>   example "red flower.jpg" becomes "red+flower.jpg".

When dealing with filenames that contains Unicode characters please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39465221/2190251) from Alastair McCormack:

> You need to convert the URL encoded Unicode string to a bytes str
>   before un-urlparsing it and decoding as UTF-8.