# Error when using continuation token on S3 download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to download a large amount of small files from an S3 bucket - I'm doing this by using the following:

```
  s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket}

    with open('/Users/hr/Desktop/s3_backup/files.csv','w') as file:

        while True:

            # The S3 API response is a large blob of metadata.
            # 'Contents' contains information about the listed objects.
            resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)

            try:
                contents = resp['Contents']
            except KeyError:
                return

            for obj in contents:
                key = obj['Key']
                file.write(key)
                file.write('\n')

            # The S3 API is paginated, returning up to 1000 keys at a time.
            # Pass the continuation token into the next response, until we
            # reach the final page (when this field is missing).
            try:
                kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
            except KeyError:
                break
```

However, after a certain amount of time I received this error message 'EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL'.

I know that there is still considerably more files on the s3 bucket. I have three questions:

1. Why is this error occurring when I haven't downloaded all files in the bucket?
2. Is there a way to start my code from the last file I downloaded from the S3 bucket (I don't want to have to re-download the file names I've already downloaded)
3. Is there a default ordering of the S3 bucket, is it alphabetical?

Comment: You should only re-run with ContinuationToken if IsTruncated is true in the response. That said, your code will be simpler if you use the Resource-level API rather than the Client-level API -- see http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects

Comment: *"'EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL' - this is because s3 is not recognising the next ContinuationToken"* ... what leads you to that interpretation of the error message?  It certainly seems like a counter-intuitive interpretation.

Comment: Resource level api didn’t work because it times out frequently - my thinking was the continuation token gave me the ability to track where I was in the downloaded (I.e. if I get an error I can restart from the point I was at).Everything else remains the same in the request except for the continuation token - hence I’m assuming this is where the problem lies.

Comment: `EndpointConnectionError` has NOTHING to do with token error, you should add  another `except EndpointConnectionError: ` and log/print the key name. Also please state your python version. A unicode/non-ascii encoded key name need special handling , i.e. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465220/get-non-ascii-filename-from-s3-notification-event-in-lambda