# AWS Lambda S3 Event Filename Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm currently using a Lambda function to process Images in scale. It works great, except for filename nuances. I've tracked it down to the S3 Event on Object Creation is including '+' values for the spaces in a filename, which seems bizarre to me, as it's being created using URL Encoding.

For example, doing an upload using the following URL:

```
signedUrl: "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/item%20copy.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=...&Content-Type=...&Expires=...&Signature=..."
```

uploads into `mybucket` and there is a final file called `item copy.jpg` in a subfolder of images.

However, when I log what the S3 Event that is sent to the lambda function, the key is:

`key":"images/item+copy.jpg"`

What am I missing here? Is there a general handling of the filenames that I'm unaware of? I could understand if these are sent using encodeURI, but they're not.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465220/get-non-ascii-filename-from-s3-notification-event-in-lambda

Comment: Did it help fix your issue? If so, we can resolve this as a duplicate.

Comment: @jarmod it did. Thank you!