# AWS Lambda Python boto3 - reading the content of a file on S3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I am writing a lambda function that reads the content of a json file which is on S3 bucket to write into a kinesis stream. Simple requirement. In the lambda I put the trigger as S3 bucket (with name of the bucket). When I drop a file into the bucket the Lambda gets triggered but says in the cloudwatch logs can't file key name . I am able to print the file name. I don't understand

```
           [ERROR] NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject 
           operation: The 
         specified key does not exist.
```

This is the code to read the file on S3

```
   import boto3
   import json
    #from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
   import time
   import csv
   from pprint import pprint

   s3 = boto3.client('s3')
   kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
        if event:
        # Read bucketname, filename from event record
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = file_obj['s3']['bucket']['name']
         filename = file_obj['s3']['object']['key']
   
        print('bucket name is ' + str(bucketname) + ' file name is ' + str(filename))
   
        # Get referenc to file on s3 bucket
        fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=filename)
        #pprint(fileObj)
   
        # Convert the data in file
        file_content = fileObj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
  
         # put the record to kinesis
   
        kinesis.put_record(Data=bytes(file_content, 'utf-8'), 
        StreamName='LambdaSourceKinesisStream',PartitionKey='basam')
   

        return "thanks"
```

The file name is agent.json

Comment: Please correct your code's indentation. What is the object key? Does it have whitespace or special characters? Example of handling that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412267/key-given-by-lambda-s3-event-cannot-be-used-when-containing-non-ascii-characters).

Comment: Please ignore my post it is working

Answer (score 0):

It is working all of a sudden. no changes were made to the code

Comment: Did you do *anything* between it failing and it now working? For example hit the Deploy button in the Lambda console, or anything else? Reason I ask is because it would be good to get to the bottom of these unusual issues you keep having, so we all understand what's going on.

Comment: Jarmod, I recently writing code in boto3 framework. Very weird stuff happened few times. One evening doesn't work, next day morning without any changes to the code starts working.